# "Extension Mathematics" by Tony Gardiner

Tags: textbooks

I would like to know if anybody has experience with the British textbook series *Extension Mathematics* in three volumes, by Tony Gardiner.

It claims to be "the first structured KS3/S1-S2 programme for gifted and talented students." (That's ages 11-14.)

First of all, is that true? Are there really no comparable books, even older ones?

Are these books well adapted to students who are, say, in the top 1% of ability, rather than 10-20%?

And are there any books with the same objective but designed for KS4 (ages 14-16)? Perhaps older O-level books?

Comment: We have used this series. I can't speak to its uniqueness in the history of mathematical teaching material. I can say, though, that it is more aimed at the top 10% than the top 1%. There is some good stuff in there, but as with most of these books, you will find different parts to be of different utility for your classes. For a good, structured course for the 1%, try: http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Circles-Russian-Experience-World/dp/0821804308

Comment: @nickjamesuk Thanks for the comments. The book by Fomin and Itenberg looks great.

Comment: @nickjamesuk if you put just a bit more detail about which bits are the "good stuff" then your comment would make a good proper answer.

Comment: I'd also tend to suspect that our usual ways of appraising "upper 1 percent" versus "upper 10 percent" are heavily skewed toward rather superficial attributes (e.g., quickness, or even "cleverness") that are not as well understood in that range as in the middle two quartiles. So attempting to make that distinction may be misguided.